# return characters left of colon

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to return all characters left of a colon(:)?

Currently returns:

```
 J441:CHRONICOBSTRUCTIVEPULMONARYDISEASEW
O80:ENCOUNTERFORFULL-TERMUNCOMPLICATEDDE
I7389:OTHERSPECIFIEDPERIPHERALVASCULARDI
```

I'd want to return J441, O80, and I7389.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT NVL(SUBSTR('J441:CHRONICOBSTRUCTIVEPULMONARYDISEASEW', 0, INSTR('J441:CHRONICOBSTRUCTIVEPULMONARYDISEASEW', ':')-1), 'J441:CHRONICOBSTRUCTIVEPULMONARYDISEASEW') AS output
  FROM DUAL
```

return J441

```
with t1 as
(
select 'J441:CHRONICOBSTRUCTIVEPULMONARYDISEASEW' as col from dual
union all
select 'O80:ENCOUNTERFORFULL-TERMUNCOMPLICATEDDE' from dual
union all
select 'I7389:OTHERSPECIFIEDPERIPHERALVASCULARDI' from dual

)  SELECT NVL(SUBSTR(col, 0, INSTR(col, ':')-1), col) AS output
  FROM t1
```

Comment: thank you that works great. Not sure exactly what each thing is doing though.

Comment: What if I wanted to get everything right of the colon?